# What's the best practice to pass AWS credentials to a docker container to use for ECS?

Tags: docker, amazon-web-services

I am trying to implement a docker container which will be deployed on Amazon ECS.

The container needs to be able to write to an S3 bucket.  So the following command will be called from inside the container:

```
aws s3api put-object ...
```

In order for the aws CLI to have access to write to S3, the credentials need somehow to be available inside the container.

The naive solution would be to just copy the contents of the .aws directory to the right place within the container, but I don't want to keep my credentials in the github repo.

What would be the best practice for making the credentials available inside the container?

Comment: Use environment variables. How are you deploying the container?

Answer (score 0):

To provide credentials to your application when it runs in ECS, the recommended approach is to specify a task role in your task definition. See the [ECS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html) for more information.